# Remove trailing space in Mac OS hostname?

Tags: prometheus, macos

I'm trying to run Prometheus on my Mac, but I get the following

```
MyHostName $ prometheus --config.file=prometheus.yaml
parse external URL "": parse "http://MyHostName :9090/": invalid character " " in host name
```

See the space between `MyHostName` and `:`?

Here's my simple `prometheus.yaml` file

```yaml
global:
  scrape_interval: 10s
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: prometheus
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - localhost:9090
```

How do I remove this space? I've tried the following

```
$ scutil --set HostName MyHostName
$ scutil --set LocalHostName MyHostName
$ scutil --set ComputerName MyHostName
```

Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I needed to restart my Mac after doing above commands, and it worked!